# OpenSSH on headless piOS closes connection immediately on connection command

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, openssh

I run OpenMediaVault and Docker/Portainer on a headless rpi4. I've never had SSH issues before, have it on a custom port but never been a problem. I ran -vvvv and see it failed to open id files that I've personally not seen before (in /.ssh I've only seen the known_hosts file.) I'll add my debug output below, I'm sure I'm just an idiot but I'd love to resolve this without wiping my system and also understand better the issue I'm having. Everything else (my various services) is still working as intended. I tried looking for a similar issue first but was not able to find anything (again may just be my fault TBF.) Thanks for your time!

My debug text triggered the spam so I put it on Pastebin instead
https://pastebin.com/W7KnCHji